# How to upload a file to Controller in conjunction with other parameters?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

I currently upload a file to my controller and it works fine:

On the client side:

```
var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i != input.files.length; i++) {
  formData.append("files", files[i]);
}    

$.ajax({
  url: "/api/ocr",
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {...}
});
```

On the server side in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IList<IFormFile> files) {
  IFormFile file = files[0];
  // process file
}
```

Now I want to send another parameter to server: connectionId.  So on the client side I added:

```
formData.append("connectionId", "123456");
```

and on the serverside, I amended the parameter to the Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IList<IFormFile> files, string connectionId) {
  ...
}
```

However, connectionId parameter is always null.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Form element contains:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

and try passing the Form element into the FormData constructor:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById(formId));
```

If your Model Binding is case sensitive, make sure the id is too:

```
<input type="text" id="connectionId"
```

and also that the connectionId input is being populated in the DOM before clicking submit using the browser's dev tools.

Comment: There is no form on the page.  Everything is being called via ajax, thus `$.ajax`

Comment: @AngryHacker it doesn't matter, you can still send `multipart/form-data` requests with `$.ajax`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax